# 500 server error for live contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, error

Latest Wordpress version with multisite setup in wordpress - not Civi.  Upgraded to civicrm 4.6.10 - also existed with civi 4.5.8 - no changes.

I can go to an existing page via the wordpress side (example.com/donate) and the civi - content shows fine.  However, if I click contribute on that page (or use the live link from civi back end) I get a 500 server error.  No obvious messages with debugging turned on (Are there log files I should review?)

Happens with stripe and paypal and even the manual option of sending by check!

It does not seem to like example.com/donate/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact

or

http://example.org/civi?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

EDIT:

Turned on PHP error reporting on my host and was delivered an error message about my google calendar plugin.

Fatal error: Class 'WP_Requirements' not found in /root/www/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/google-calendar-events.php on line 46

Deactivation of the Plugin allows the system to process normally.

Same issue: posted yesterday to developer - no response yet: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-not-compatible-with-civicrm-profiles

Comment: Sounds like a PHP error is being thrown but output is suppressed. First stop is to look at your logs and post any relevant errors as part of your question.

Comment: No errors shown in the log after clearing log and revisiting page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned on PHP error reporting on my host and was delivered an error message about my google calendar plugin.

Fatal error: Class 'WP_Requirements' not found in /root/www/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/google-calendar-events.php on line 46

Deactivation of the Plugin allows the system to process normally.

Same issue: posted yesterday to developer - no response yet: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-not-compatible-with-civicrm-profiles

Answer (score 0):

Check your civicrm config log file. You are getting donate page working because of cache file. To get the proper error message, you need to remove the civicrm temporary (templates_c) folder and enable the debugging. Also check for common folder in civicrm ( in version 4.6.10 it's missing for drupal release).

Comment: I'd cleared the cache file with upgrade - still same issue.  I can change processor and have same issue as well.  Debugging is turned on and I'm running wordpress.

Comment: Check after rebuild ing the civicrm menu.